# Restkit: maps to two responseDescriptor in one request

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a request gives me two part of data, the json looks like this

```
{
    "banner_content":
    [
        {
            "activi_id":"1",
            "activi_pic":
        },
        {
            "activi_id":"2",
            "activi_pic":
        },
    ],
    "categories":
    [
        {...},
        {...},
    ]
}
```

When I write `responseDescriptor` to map the data, I have found I must define a model which contains `banner_content` array and `categories` array (I don't want to )
or else I have to write two responseDescriptors to do, when the request is done, I have to get the two parts of data from `(RKMappingResult *)mappingResult`
then get array like `[mappingResult objectForKey:@"banner_content"]` and  `[mappingResult objectForKey:@"categories"]`
it's weird

below is my code 
File:RCategory.m

```
@implementation RCategory


 + (NSDictionary *)_mapping {
     return @{@"title" : @"title"};
}

 + (RKObjectMapping *)mapping {

    // Setup our object mappings
    RKObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
    [categoryMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[[self class] _mapping]];

     RKObjectMapping *itemMapping = [RCategoryItem mapping];

    RKRelationshipMapping* relationShipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping      relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"content"
                                                                                              toKeyPath:@"items"
                                                                                       withMapping:itemMapping];
[categoryMapping addPropertyMapping:relationShipMapping];

    return categoryMapping;
}

@end
```

File:RAd.m ignored

File:viewController.m

```
- (void)loadCategory {
    // Load the object model via RestKit
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

    RKObjectMapping *categoryMapping = [RCategory mapping];

    RKResponseDescriptor *categoryResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:categoryMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:@"category"
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    RKObjectMapping *adsMapping = [RAd mapping];
    RKResponseDescriptor *adResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:adsMapping
                                                                                                method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                           pathPattern:nil
                                                                                               keyPath:@"banner_content"
                                                                                           statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

     //** DO I MUST ADD TWO RESPONSE_DESCRIPTOR FOR ONE REQUEST??**
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:categoryResponseDescriptor];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:adResponseDescriptor];

    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:RPATH(CATEGORY_PATH)
                     parameters:nil
                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                            NSArray* statuses = [mappingResult array];
                            [self.categories addObjectsFromArray:statuses];
                            if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
                                [self.tableView reloadData];
                            }
                        }
                        failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                                           delegate:nil
                                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
                            [alert show];
                            NSLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);
                        }];

}
```

Does anybody have a better way to solve my problem?
BTW I write `-mapping` in the Model Class, It's the easiest and best way I can think out
I would like to know how do you write the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 response descriptors because the response has 2 logically separate parts. This is fine. If you were using Core Data then you wouldn't be concerned as all your objects would simply be saved to the context and you can fetch them as required. With object mapping, if you don't care about the grouping then you can get an array of all objects from the mapping result.

Creating your mappings from data returned by the model objects is fine - but it does limit you because you can only have one source key per destination key. What happens when you have a different response for the same object with a different key that means the same as some other key (hopefully you don't, but it all depends on the server API).

Comment: the categories and banner_content array are what I needed, But I don't want they are wrapped in one Model,I don't think I need two rDescriptor if I wrapper categories and banner_content

you say `Creating your mappings from data returned by the model objects is fine`, it's my doubt too, how do you do the mapping? 

I write mapping in MyModels.m, if I need a new responseDescriptor I can quick assign a new for another keypath, good or bad?

AND as objectManager's a singeton, maybe I don’t need addResponseDescriptor every time before a REQUEST. 
BUT how to manage the ResponseDescriptors?

Comment: Personally, I have a singleton that owns my data model and controls access to it (MyDataController). It provides an interface in terms of my model objects and has methods for getting / editing / requesting. It specifies all of the mappings. I often have several `RKObjectMapping` instances.

Comment: Totally agree with Wain, having 2 response descriptors and specifying which one to use with mapping using "keyPath" argument - is the best solution in this case.